# how should i use @Value correct?

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations

I use spring boot starter 2.1.3 with dubbo-starter.

If you have any idea or suggestion , please let me know , thanks!

[as you see it should not be null value , i don't know why.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEnkE.png)

Answer (score 1):

`@Value` annotation looks for value from `application.property` file or `application.yml` file.

You can define values in these files then inject them using `@Value`.

See [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-random-values) to load values from `.property` or [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-loading-yaml) to use `.yml` file.

[Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties) is a better way to load configurations.

You may also want to read about the order Spring Boot uses to load configurations from different environments/files [Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config).

HTH.

Comment: I found the resolver [PropertySourcesPropertyResolver] skipped replacing the ${rabbit.username} property.

Comment: @Bean
public MapperScannerConfigurer getMapperScannerConfigurer() {
    MapperScannerConfigurer scannerConfigurer = new MapperScannerConfigurer();
    scannerConfigurer.setBasePackage("com.XXX.XXX.dao.biz");
 ..........
    return scannerConfigurer;
}